# Solving the ODE $y''-2x^2y'+4xy=x^2+2x+2$ using power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am trying to solve this nonhomogeneous ODE:

$$y''-2x^2y'+4xy=x^2+2x+2$$

I know it's a power series, but when I get down to the very end, I end up with a $C_0$ term, a $C_1$ term, and a $C_2$ term. I am supposed to only have a $C_0$ and $C_1$ term. I cannot find any other ways to solve this, and Wolfram is not helping either.

Any ideas or suggestions?

So my final solution is $$y=c_0+Xc_1+X^2-\frac23X^3c_0-\frac16x^4c_1+0-\frac{2}{45}X^6c_0$$ ....etc

The $X^2$ term is messing me up, because i need this solution for $y_1(x)$ in terms of $c_0$ and $y_2(x)$ in terms of $c_1$..... so that extra $x^2$ is because I got $c_2=1$.

Comment: yeah, does that help?

Comment: I've tried quite a few different ways, i just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The power series $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ is determined by $c_0$ and $c_1$. Plugging it into the equation and comparing the free terms on both sides yields
$$
2c_2=2
$$
Hence $c_2 = 1$, as you got. You probably found it strange that this coefficient does not depend on $c_0, c_1$. But such is the nature of this nonhomogeneous equation: it forces every solution to have $y''(0)=2$, hence $c_2=1$.

The process continues: comparing the coefficients of $x^1$ on both sides yields
$$
6c_3+4c_0 = 2
$$
which gives $c_3$. Similarly, $c_4$ is obtained from the coefficients of $x^2$. If you just need a few terms of the series, it is reasonable to continue by hand as I did so far. If you need the whole series, there is a recurrence relation to be solved: you get $c_n$ from the coefficients of $x^{n-2}$,
$$
n(n-1)c_n-2(n-3)c_{n-3}+4c_{n-3} = 0 \quad  \text{(for $n>4$)}
$$

Comment: Thanks, i sort of understand what your saying, but this really didn't help me at all with solving the ODE.... my solution looks like $$y=Co+C1x+x^2-2/3Cox^3-2/12C1x^4-2/45x^6Co-2/126C1x^7$$.....i don't understand what to do with this form this point.